# wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0) error shown

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this statement in my application

```
User.all(:conditions => "status <> 3", :order => "firstname, lastname").collect{|x| [x.name, x.id.to_s]}
```

where I am trying to find all the users  and sort them by first name and last name.

When I try using this statement it gives me the error

> wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0).

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: What function is the error being caused by?

Comment: `code`                                                                                                       def user_options                                                                                              options = User.all(:conditions => "status <> 3", :order => "firstname, lastname").collect{|x| [x.name, x.id.to_s]}
 end

Comment: No, what function in the snippet above has the wrong number of arguments supplied? The error should say.

Comment: The error shows this line `options = User.all(:conditions => "status <> 3", :order => "firstname, lastname").collect{|x| [x.name, x.id.to_s]}`

Comment: I know the query needs to be changed for rails 4 by not sure how to change it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to write this

```
User.where('status <> 3').order(:firstname, :lastname).pluck(:name, :id)
```

The only difference is that the id won't be converted to a string so you can just append `.map { |res| res[1] = res[1].to_s; res }` if you really need this.

Comment: using the query as `options = User.where('status <> 3').order(:firstname, :lastname).collect{|x| [x.name, x.id.to_s]}`worked...

Comment: Just a note here, `pluck` can potentially perform better. If you use `collect` it means that you instantiate all `ActiveRecord` objects, while `pluck` will return a more "lightweight" array. I think the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-pluck) puts it nicely. 
_"Use pluck as a shortcut to select one or more attributes without loading a bunch of records just to grab the attributes you want."_